# On narrowing casts in C# between signed and unsigned integral types

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I seek to get a few thing confirmed regarding the way narrowing casts work with integral types in C# (5.0, .NET Framework 4.0/4.5). Bottom line: Can I be sure that the underlying bytes of integral types stay the same, both in order and value, when casting between signed and unsigned?

Let's say that I do the following:

```
short shortVal = -20000;
ushort ushortVal = (ushort)shortVal;
```

Now, the experiments I've done so far, shows me that the bytes in following two byte arrays:

```
byte[] shortBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(shortVal);
byte[] ushortBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ushortVal);
```

do NOT differ. I have done this exact experiment with an explicit narrowing cast from `short` to `ushort` with the value of `shortVal` in the range from `Int16.MinValue` to `Int16.MaxValue`. All 2^16 cases checks out fine. The actual interpreted value though, is naturally re-interpreted since the bytes stay the same. I assume the signed integral types use two's complement to represent signed values (is this true?)

I need to know, if I can count on these conversion always being "byte-safe" - as in not changing the underlying bytes and their order. This also goes for conversion the other way, from unsigned to signed. Are these conversion exact reverses of each other? I am focused mostly on short/ushort and int/uint. But all integral types are of interest.

These detail are likely up to implementation of the technology behind C# and the CLR. I am here strictly focused on the CLR for Windows 32/64 bit.

Comment: Yes. C# signed integral types use the two's complement representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be quite tricky.

CLR does use two's complement for signed integral number representation on x86/x64 architectures (as you observed in your test), and it's unlikely to change in the near future, because the architecture itself has good support for it. It's safe to assume it will stay like this for a while.

On the other hand, I haven't found any mention of this in either CLI or C# specifications, so you can't count on it in general, especially in face of other architectures and/or CLI implementations.

So it depends on what you want to use this on. I would stay away from depending on implementation details like this if possible, and use higher level serialization tools to convert to/from any binary representation.

Comment: You know MODBUS? An older slave/master industrial protocol. I am building some software dealing with this protocol. Although I am using a library that deals with all low-level stuff, this library uses `short` in its public interface (since MODBUS use 16-bit wide registers). I wanted to see if changing the use of `short` to `ushort` on higher-levels in my code would have any impact. It seems not - at the moment. A runtime check is probably good, just in case.

Comment: I see, that's actually good for you - as long as the library takes care of the binary conversion and exposes `short`, you should be safe to cast to `ushort` (and back, in unchecked context), if you don't rely on its binary representation elsewhere.